# Where is the Midgard Dwarf Valkyrie?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, books, content-identification

I was perusing *Frostburn 3.5* a few days ago, reading about Midgard Dwarves.

I remember opening another rulebook or Web Enhancement that had an NPC/Monster/Prc that was a female Midgard Dwarf Valkyrie. Now I can't remember where I saw it. The format/layout for the pages were the standard for 3.5 (Red/Rust Boarder, white background) so I don't think it was from a Forgotten Realms source (I saw *Berronar Valkyrie* from *Champions of Valor*, this was not what I remember).

Does anyone remember a Midgard Dwarf Valkyrie? Where can I find this material?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Searching my collection, I find that Midgard Dwarves are only in *Frostburn* and that Valkyries are only in *Tome of Battle* and *Deities and Demigods*. If anything, I think that you're thinking of the Einherjar from *Deities and Demigods*. They're chosen by the Valkyries and the first example given for them in *Deities and Demigods* is an Einherjar Dwarf, so it might make sense that you merged the two when you read.

For what it's worth, the 3.5e revision to *Deities and Demigods* claims that only humans can be Valkyries. It says:

> *Valkyries are simply human female paladins with the einherjar template.*

although this probably contradicts *Tome of Battle*. I have no idea which of those two is considered the primary source.